# Emacs org-agenda - header

Tags: org-agenda

I'am new with emacs.  I try using org-agenda.  I wonder if we can customize the header with a different color or font. I'am talking about this : org-agenda-overriding-header.
Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move to org agenda header and run `M-x describe-text-properties` see text properties at POS, after that you will find you need to customize `org-agenda-structure` face.